# Why is exporting/importing default ES module properties faster than names module properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I'm reading the Material UI documentation, and it states:

> Notice that in the above example, we used:
>   `import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';` instead of
>   `import {RaisedButton} from 'material-ui';` This will make your build
>   process faster and your build output smaller.

I cannot find any justification for why the use of default exports makes the build process faster or build output smaller.

My manager is asking us to refrain from using default exports, however a smaller build size is an important target for this project. I mentioned this quote by Material UI, and they said to find proof. I'd like some proof, please, as my attempts to compile it with Babel have shown `default` to be larger if anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key thing is not whether the module has a default export or not, but the fact that you import a module that includes all the Material UI Components (the `material-ui` module) instead of the module that includes only the `RaisedButton` component (the `material-ui/RaisedButton` module).

To be absolutely clear: We should be using the module that only includes a single component, i.e. `material-ui/RaisedButton`.

Comment: Exactly. I believe the material-ui docs also say that if you have tree-shaking enabled, it doesn't matter which import you use.

Comment: Wow, I'm dumb. It's not emphasizing the curly braces; it's emphasizing the file path. Thanks!

Comment: That's partially right, @Sidney. It does not affect the production bundle size when tree shaking. However, while developing we still take the hit from parsing and executing all that JavaScript.

Comment: @Sidney there is an absolute benefit to always preferring single component imports to equivalent named imports from module namespace, whether or not you have tree-shaking enabled, because it _reduces duration of compiling_. By "compiling" I mean transpiling / bundling / tree-shaking / minifying. So even if the outcome of the runtime code is ultimately the same, you still have faster compilation time.

Comment: @Bergi I think that goes without saying... I said nothing about syntax.